# Bringing over CSS style to jquery code

Tags: jquery, css

My code is only half working - it is bringing over font-size and font-family but nothing else :(. Here is the CSS:

```
#block2 {
    background-color: #99F5F5;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #7AC4C4;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 355px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn1').click(function() {
        $("ul").addClass("#block2").append("<li>" + $("#txt1").val() + "</li>");
        $("#txt1").val("").focus();
    });
});
```

Like I said above - when I click btn1 I append a new 'li' but the CSS is only bringing over the font-size and font-width. Please help!! I'd like for all of #block2 to work when I append a new 'li'.

Comment: `$("#txt1").val("").focus();` - this is wrong, should be `$("#txt1").focus();`

Comment: Open your developers console and see which styles get overwritten, then add !important to those styles.

Comment: @odedta What's wrong in that? It should work

Comment: `#block2` is incorrect classname.

Comment: @Tushar, I don't think it's a compliation error but he is basically trying to focus a number.

Comment: you are using addClass, `.` when your css is an ID `#`

Comment: Changing the ID to Class had the same result - using !important gave me different results but none gave me my entire .block2 styling...

Comment: Is there another way to add CSS style to jquery code without using 'addClass' ?

Answer (score 3):

Make the change in the CSS, you were declaring block2 as an ID `#` instead of a class `.`

```
.block2 {
    background-color: #99F5F5;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #7AC4C4;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 355px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Here is Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn1').click(function() {
        $("ul").addClass("block2").append("<li>" + $("#txt1").val() + "</li>");
        $("#txt1").val("").focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: This did the exact same thing as my code above. Just pulled over font-size and font-family. I tried the !important and the font size and font-family went to default and when I placed a !important on border color, my border disappeared, and if I don't use !important on border color, the border comes out black...it seems my CSS is acting extremely weird :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my HTML. I had class=block2 on my 'ul'. I deleted the class out of the HTML and left it in CSS, put .addClass on its on line in jquery and did 'li' instead of 'ul' and it works nicely. Thanks everyone for making me understand better!!!